# Can a verb be an object complement like the verb "boil" in this sentence?

Tags: parsing

Could someone please parse this sentence?

> She watched the pot boil slowly.

Also, does *slowly* here refer to *the process of boiling* or "her" *act of watching the pot boil*?

Comment: It's more likely "boil" and "slowly" go together and it's the pot that is boiling slowly. How can one watch sth *slowly*, by the way?

Comment: Thank you, @Andrew Tobilko. What about parsing, though? :)

Comment: No: verbs cannot function as object complements. "Watch" is a catenative verb and the subordinate infinitival clause "boil slowly" is its catenative complement. Note that "the pot" is the syntactic object of "watch" and the understood subject of the subordinate clause. The natural interpretation of "slowly" is that it modifies "boil".

Comment: The other thing that's odd about this sentence is that if taken literally, it implies that the *pot* is boiling, rather than its contents.  This is of course a standard idiom and we understand that it's talking about the contents rather than the pot itself, but it would need to get a *lot* hotter to cause a metal pot to reach its boiling point than whatever liquid is contained within it...

Comment: Of course, simply substitute "anxiously" or "intently" and the answer is rather different.  (-:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *She watched the pot* [*boil slowly*].

No: verbs cannot function as object complements.

This is a catenative construction in which "watch" is a catenative verb and the subordinate infinitival clause "boil slowly" is its catenative complement.

Note that the noun phrase "the pot" is the syntactic object of "watch" and the understood subject of the subordinate clause. The natural interpretation of "slowly" is that it modifies "boil".

The term 'catenative' comes from the Latin word for "chain, for the construction is repeatable in a way that enables us to form a chain of verbs in which all but the last have a non-finite complement. In your example, the chain is short -- just two verbs separated by the NP "the pot".